# How to strip suffix with basename inside a find -exec command?

Tags: linux, command-line, find, string-manipulation

I have not found a way to do the following example with find:

```
$ find . -name "*.mp3" -exec echo  $(basename "{}" ".mp3") \;
```

I expected the `basename` command to remove the extension.  It does not.  For example:

```
$ find . -name "*.mp3" -exec ls  $(basename "{}" ".mp3") \;
'Soul Man.mp3'
'Hold On! I'\''m A Comin'\''.mp3'
```

I'm also hoping someone can explain what's happening here?  One would think the result would be more like:

```
ls: cannot access 'Soul Man': No such file or directory
```

Is there an effective way to remove the extension with in the `find`'s `-exec` command string?

Answer (score 2):

`find` generates a list of files. You can either process those files directly inside the command (typically with `-exec sh -c '...' _ {} +`) or by passing the list to another tool. The appropriate solution depends on your actual requirement.

1. Process directly

   Here I am simply printing the file name surrounded by `>>` … `<<` symbols. The `${f##*/}` construct removes as many `*/` pattern matches from the front of the `$f` variable as possible (i.e. it implements `basename` and removes the pathname component), and the `${f%.mp3}` returns the value of (the new) `$f` without a trailing `.mp3` (remember that `$f` is is the loop variable iterating across a set of file names generated by `find`):

   ```
   find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do f=${f##*/}; printf ">> %s <<\n" "${f%.mp3}"; done' _ {} +
   ```
2. Filter onwards

   Here we can filter the output from `find` by removing a trailing `.mp3` from every line of output. There are two variants; the first one uses GNU extensions to handle filenames that might contain nonprinting characters such as *newline*; the second uses more standard tools but is more limited in the set of file names it can process:

   ```
   # NUL-terminated file names
   find . -name '*.mp3' -print0 | sed -Ez 's!^.*/(.*)\.mp3$!\1!'
   ```

   You will get the set of filenames each ended with NUL rather than newline. Filter through `tr '\0' '\n'` to see the output visually.

   ```
   # Newline-terminated file names
   find . -name '*.mp3' -print | sed 's!^.*/(.*)\.mp3$!\1!'
   ```

---

Now an explanation for your own code not working:

> ```
> find . -name "*.mp3" -exec ls -d $(basename "{}" ".mp3") \;
> ```

You haven't quoted the segment passed to `-exec`, so the shell gets it *before* execution of `find` as part of its normal parsing and variable interpolation. Specifically, the `$(basename "{}" ".mp3")` is evaluated - once - before the command runs.

```
basename "{}" ".mp3" 
{}
```

so your `find` is actually this command (I've left the `\` preceding the `;` so you can copy and paste this; in reality it too would have been removed and the `;` passed literally to `find`):

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec ls {} \;
```

You could avoid the pre-execution evaluation exactly as usual by putting the string into single quotes:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec 'ls $(basename "{}" ".mp3")' \;
```

However, this will fail in any subdirectory of the current directory, as `basename` *by definition* removes the path component.

Generally speaking, you should consider `ls` to be a tool for visual reference. For programmatic use of file/directory names, there are usually much better alternatives and choosing the right alternative depends on the actual goal.

Comment: [@roaima...](https://superuser.com/users/332907/roaima) The use of `ls` was merely to illustrate the "effect", the actual plan is 
to invoke a script to complete processing.  Hoepfully, I will have time to test this suggestion soon.   One thing I've seen work is to `source` a `bash` script and provide `{ }` as the argument.  Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -c 'for arg; do echo "${arg%.*}"; done' bash {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add an answer with only the explanation for the result observed:

1. `$(basename "{}" ".mp3")` gets expanded by the shell first
2. Since `basename "{}" ".mp3"` returns `{}`, the actual full command of `find` that gets executed would be `find . -name "*.mp3" -exec ls {} \;`
3. As a result, `ls X` is executed for every X returned in `find . -name "*.mp3"`